# R, the environment of mclapply and removing variables

Tags: r, memory, parallel-processing, mclapply

I am having trouble understanding the behave of mclapply (or maybe something else).

I do something like:

```
opt.Models = mclapply(1:100, mc.cores=20, function(i){
    res = loadResult(reg, id=i)    
    return(post.Process(res))
  })
```

`loadResult` loads **one** result from a earlier saved BatchJob session. So, the `res` object needs ~170MB (roughly all 100 objects are the same size +/-5MB).
When executing the piece of code, the memory footprint is as expected: 170MB*20= ~3.5GB (I used 20 cores).
When executing this piece of code for the second time, my machine inhales a vast amount of memory (more than available - so I stop execution). What is expected because, again, `mclapply`forks the complete environment for each child and my environment now has the big `opt.Models` variable with ~10GB. Therefore 10*20=200GB would be required.

When I remove opt.Models, `rm(opt.Models)`, I still run into the same problem. mclapply consumes more memory than available (btw: 90GB).
So, which environment does mclapply fork, or isn't opt.Models totally gone? I can't see it using `ls()`.

Maybe one of you has observed something similar.

Best regards,

Mario

Comment: I don't understand why you don't limit the number of cores to a more reasonable value.

Comment: Because that wasn't my problem. I was just wondering why that memory wasn't released. Reducing the cores would just result in a slower convergence of the effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call the `gc` function after removing the variable so that the memory associated with the object is freed by the garbage collector sooner rather than later. The `rm` function only removes the reference to the data, while the actual object may continue to exist until the garbage collector eventually runs.

You may also want to call `gc` before the first `mclapply` to make testing easier:

```
gc()
opt.Models = mclapply(1:100, mc.cores=20, function(i){
    res = loadResult(reg, id=i)    
    return(post.Process(res))
  })

# presumably do something with opt.Models...

rm(opt.Models)
gc()  # free up memory before forking

opt.Models = mclapply(1:100, mc.cores=20, function(i){
    res = loadResult(reg, id=i)    
    return(post.Process(res))
  })
```